# NHibernate IPostInsertEventListener : Insert executed multiple times

Tags: events, nhibernate, testing, triggers, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to test a simple NHibernate-based auditing mechanism that stores one row per changed property into a changelog table. What it actually does, is perform the actual insert statement as expected and perform the audit logging twice.

So, this is what I do:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=audittest;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
FluentConfiguration config = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                                        .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString)).ShowSql())
                                                        .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.Add<Class1ClassMap>())
                                                        .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.Add<ChangeLogMap>())
                                                        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
                                                        {
                                                            NHibernateAuditListener listener = new NHibernateAuditListener();
                                                            cfg.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PostInsert, new[] { listener });
                                                        });
ISessionFactory sf =  config.BuildSessionFactory();
ISession session = sf.OpenSession();
using (ITransaction tr = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(new Class1()
        {
            FirstName="Peter",
            LastName="Pan",
            Id=100

        });
    tr.Commit();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Altered the logging code to something simple to see the failure:

```
public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent @event)
{
    if (@event.Entity is IAuditable)
    {                
        Console.WriteLine("----write audit----");
        for (int index = 0; index < @event.State.Length; index++)
            Console.WriteLine("----store changes of property {0}----",
                              @event.Persister.PropertyNames[index]);
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO "Class1" (FirstName, LastName, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); @p0 = 'Peter' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 'Pan' [Type: String (0)], @p2 = 1 [Type: Int64 (0)]
----write audit----
----store changes of property FirstName----
----store changes of property LastName----
----write audit----
----store changes of property FirstName----
----store changes of property LastName----
```

As you see, it's not the EventHandler code that's erroneous, but the framework calling it that behaves unexpectedly (calling the OnPostInsert method twice). Any ideas why this is happening?

[SAMPLE PROJECT DOWNLOAD](https://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/attach/b6aae746de89e550/ConsoleApplication1.zip?part=4&authuser=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay everybody, the problem exists in the detail of the handling within the programm. You are building up a FluentConfiguration-instance which on the fly creates the the basic NHibernate configuration.

This is done on the call of these 2 lines (variable config is of type `FluentConfiguration`):

```
new SchemaExport(config.BuildConfiguration()).Create(true, true);
```

and

```
ISessionFactory sf = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

The FluentConfiguration caches the first created instance and reuses it for creating the new instance for the `ISessionFactory`-instance. On both calls the `ExposeConfiguration` of `FluentConfiguration` instance is called. So there are 2 instances of the `NHibernateAuditListener` within the session that is persisting the data.

Try it like this:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=audittest;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
var config = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                                    .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString)).ShowSql())
                                                    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.Add<Class1ClassMap>())
                                                    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.Add<ChangeLogMap>())
                                                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
                                                    {
                                                        NHibernateAuditListener listener = new NHibernateAuditListener();
                                                        cfg.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PostInsert, new[] { listener });
                                                    })
                                                    .BuildConfiguration();
new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, true);
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");

ISessionFactory sf =  config.BuildSessionFactory();
ISession session = sf.OpenSession();
using (ITransaction tr = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(new Class1()
    {
        FirstName="Peter",
        LastName="Pan",
        Id=100

    });
tr.Commit();
}
```

Within `config` you have now the real NHibernate Configuration instance, with only one Listener registered.

Got it?!

Comment: Thanks, MacX. Once again, you rescued me from self-inflicted pain!